# How to embed links from intranet Jira, in Confluence cloud document

Tags: links, confluence, jira

When I use Confluence and Jira on the cloud (e.g. use the SaaS as an Atlassian customer), I can paste a link of a Jira issue into a Confluence document, and the issue's Summary field text is automatically displayed, in the Confluence document, as a "live link" to the Jira issue.

But when I do the same with a link from my company's internal Jira deployment, this does not work. I only get the link text (https://... ) .

Obviously there are some login/permission issues, as I am now "asking" the external Confluence to read something from our protected Intranet.

The question: Is it possible to somehow set things so that the ability to "pull" the Summary text by Confluence from our Intranet Jira will work?

Thanks,
Michael

Answer (score 1):

There needs to be an Application Link between Jira and Confluence for the Jira issue macro to work. This is set up automatically in the Jira/Confluence cloud sites. You would need to allow access to the Internet Jira from the cloud, which your network admins and security team will want to review carefully

Comment: I suspected our admins will need to be involved :-) with all the justified cybersecurity concerns.
Thanks!